# How does a subsidiary "upstream" a contract in the following scenario?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, subsidiaries

Company B is an 80%-owned subsidiary of Company A. Company B has just signed a contract with Company C. Company A wants the contract (its rights and obligations) for itself.

Can Company A acquire the contract from Company B by taking over 100% of Company B, thereby making it a wholly owned subsidiary? Can it use some other mechanism such as a purchase transfer or assignment of interests to acquire the contract? Or must Company A keep Company B's contract separate even if B is a subsidiary? Must company C agree if this expands the scope of the contract (which was initially for all of "B's" needs of a particular product, and A wants it to supply of all of its needs?

Comment: Does the contract say it is no-transferable? Pretty important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the contract is transferable then B can transfer the agreement to A regardless of C's opinion. Otherwise A could certainly buy rest of B and then move employees from A to B to  carry out of the contract and the profit would flow to A.